# Change Presentation Type for Modal View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, segue

In storyboard when you draw a Segue to a modal view controller you can select the type of Presentation, Full Screen, Page Sheet, Form Sheet, etc.

I am doing presenting a modal viewcontroller from a XIB, and it's presenting it in full screen. How do I programmatically change it to Page Sheet or Form Sheet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `UIViewController` (code), you can set how the new `UIViewController` will be presented. The property you can access:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIModalTransitionStyle modalTransitionStyle
```

And the different types:

```
typedef enum {
   UIModalPresentationFullScreen = 0,
   UIModalPresentationPageSheet,
   UIModalPresentationFormSheet,
   UIModalPresentationCurrentContext,
} UIModalPresentationStyle;
```

In the code:

```
MyViewController *controllerThatWillBePresented = ...
controllerThatWillBePresented.modalTransitionStyle = // The one you want
[self presentModalViewController:controllerThatWillBePresented animated:YES];
```

Comment: Where do I put the typedef enum at?

Comment: ok, so I put it in the header, but I am getting "Redefintion of enumerator for all the entries in the enum.

Comment: @JackyBoy, isn't that suppose to be `.modalPresentationStyle` instead of `.modalTransitionStyle`?